# how to return a big number using c++ console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, console-application, return-value

I have a console application makes some calculations and I want to return 8 digit number which later will be used by a MFC dll project.

How can i return that number, so that when console application exe is run inside MFC project I can use that number for something else in my MFC application.

I am asking this because I have program that runs as a console application but does not run under MFC even I tried hard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want one exe to read the output of another exe. You will either use some inter-process communication mechanism. Or caller project will have to read STDOUT stream on callee process while callee write the result to STDOUT.

Comment: console app is exe but other part which is MFC is a dll project is used by another program. Console app does not have any console output to show( at least I dont want it). It calculates a number which is 8 digit as I mentioned. I just want that number but I dont know waht is the best way to get it

Comment: @user Other inter-process communication mechanisms include *shared memory*, *pipes*, *sockets*, etc. Pick your poison. Or fix the application.

Comment: Thanks guys, instead, I have to find another way